# Selenium IDE playback is not working

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-rc, selenium-ide

Changed Selenium IDE source code format by following these steps:

Options>>Formats>>Python2/UT/RC>>Ok
 Format>>Python2/UT/RC
 Recorded code in IDE stop

Now playback button is not enabled. Try to export code to Python2/UT/RC to Eclipse(Python) enabled but there also it is not working, when trying to execute it is opening a box with "Ant" and close.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to revert the steps to work.
Options>Formats>HTML

It should work.